# Closing a div box after it has been added to the DOM (html body) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I was hoping to get some help. I set up a JSfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/y7mEY/102/

I was looking to have the grey `div` box that appears when the input box is clicked (that will have the search options in it) to close when I click anywhere outside it.

I would like to not load jquery and therefore keep everything in javascript.

Any help?

code below:

#### HTML

```
<div id = "searchHousing">
    <input type="text" name="value" id="fillIn"> 
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.searchBox {

    position: absolute; 
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color:black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: grey;

}

#fillIn {

    width: 200px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;

#searchHousing {

float: left;

}
```

#### Javascript:

```
var inputSearch = document.getElementById('fillIn');

inputSearch.onclick = function() {
    var searchBox = document.createElement("div"); 
    searchBox.className = "searchBox";
    document.getElementById('searchHousing').appendChild(searchBox);
};
```

Thanks,
Ewan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to not create new 'div' on click event. This will result in multiple "searchBox" divs when the input box is clicked multiple times. Needless to say, it will require cleanup effort to remove duplicated divs.

Rather, create the searchBox div in HTML and toggle it's visibility on javascript events.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7mEY/109/

[

```
var inputSearch = document.getElementById('fillIn');

inputSearch.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('searchBox').style.display = 'block';
};
inputSearch.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById('searchBox').style.display = 'none';
};
```

]

Comment: Genius, of course i was approaching the issue in a very round about way trying to add then remove, as apposed to just hiding and showing. Thank you, simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your current approach, simply use the "onblur" event to remove the element when the element loses focus.

```
inputSearch.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById('searchHousing').removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("searchBox")[0]);
}
```

But as CVG mentions, creating/deleting elements live is a fairly bad idea.

Comment: I put this in and it's nice there are so many options in .js. Thanks for your help, i ended up using CVG's method but this is helpful for the future! Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You'll be creating div elements all the time, which isn't any good. You could something along the lines of toggling the display attribute.

Just to make sure, if you want the searchBox to stay open and only close if you're clicking outside the searchBox **and** fillin elements, then you can just follow the click events and only toggle the display if you're clicking outside both. The other methods will just close it out as long as you're not typing in the input, and if you want to place tools or something within the div, then that would be useless.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id != "searchBox" && e.target.id != "fillIn")
        document.getElementById("searchBox").style.display="none";
});
```

Full demonstration: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D88Kz/)

Comment: Didn't know about the .onblur feature! Thanks for your help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with onBlur as the other answers suggest is that you will then hide the search options div every time you click anything in it (since the input field will lose focus). This is probably not what you're looking for. Instead, you can add a click handler for the document to hide the search options, and then add a click handler for the search housing to prevent event propagation (which keeps the document click handler from hiding the options).

- If you click the input box, the handler shows the options
- If you click the input box or the options, the event propagation stops
- If you click anywhere in the document besides the input box or options, the options are hidden

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpjava/y7mEY/114/)

```
var inputSearch = document.getElementById('fillIn');
var searchHousing = document.getElementById('searchHousing')

inputSearch.onclick = function(event) {
  document.getElementById('searchBox').style.display = 'block';
};
searchHousing.onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // won't be passed to document.onclick
};
document.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('searchBox').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: @user3093045: I wonder why you find jQuery so distasteful here. Adding event handlers is one of the most error-prone activities when considering different browsers. Can you verify that you've taken that into account?

Comment: Hi Keith, I know it may sounds silly but I feel like I am cheating by using jQuery. 
Plus loading the library slows things down I hear? I want to get really good with Javascript and I suppose jQuery muddies the water.
I have asked developers at work and they agree it is better for browser support... So i suppose i am not future proofing my code, however it's still early days. I'm sure retrospectively it will be a bad idea to just develop for Chrome. Thanks for your advice, going to go fiddle with what you've posted now :)

Comment: @user3093045. If you end up using my suggestion, I would appreciate an upvote. Anyway, it all depends on your audience and your goals. If you can control the browsers, great. If you want to learn javascript I would suggest a mixture of writing your own code but also reading the source code of a few of other frameworks. That's where you learn things that you just wouldn't think of. The right time to choose something like jQuery is this: you need to develop fast and work with a lot of DOM elements to finish your application.

Comment: If your application *is* a framework, then you use something like jQuery as a guide to give you ideas of what to provide and how to make it safe, scalable, performant, etc.